# Upgrading to SQL Server 2014 SP3 _ Clarifications help needed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, service-pack

We have SQL Server 2014 SP2 GDR with below:

1. Availability Groups
2. TDE enabled for structured data
3. EFS enabled for unstructured data

Now the DBs are with AOAGs and encrypted ,  I am planning to upgrade current SQL Server 2014 SP2 GDR to SQL Server 2014 SP3. Can anyone help me with any issues / pre-requisites or anything that can happen adversely.

Though I am planning first upgrade DEVELOPMENT / STAGING , please share your thoughts as I need to upgrade my PROD . I am little worried as the DBs are with TDE + EFS . Does encryption has any linkage with SP3 upgrade.

Comment: What exactly are you concerned about?  Apply the patch to the secondary(ies), once complete, perform a manual failover, then patch the previous primary node.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Service Packs on same major version ( 2014 ) does not have any impacts on these features.

Comment: Thank you @Hessam Boroumand .